# Issue while creating csv with awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to create a csv file with AWK. I am using output file separator to add commas for columns. But there is one column whose name is separated by space and Its also getting processed in the output with comma.

```
cat test.txt | head -n 3
Vulnerability ID        Package                                     Severity          Fix                     Vulnerability URL
CVE-2017-1000408        libc-bin-2.24-11+deb9u3                     High              2.24-11+deb9u4          https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2017-1000408
CVE-2017-1000408        libc-dev-bin-2.24-11+deb9u3                 High              2.24-11+deb9u4          https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2017-1000408
```

Command:

```
cat test.txt | awk -F' ' 'BEGIN{OFS=",";} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5;}' > file.csv
```

Output:

```
Vulnerability,ID,Package,Severity,Fix
CVE-2017-1000408,libc-bin-2.24-11+deb9u3,High,2.24-11+deb9u4,https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2017-1000408
CVE-2017-1000408,libc-dev-bin-2.24-11+deb9u3,High,2.24-11+deb9u4,https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2017-1000408
```

Expected Output:

```
Vulnerability ID,Package,Severity,Fix,Vulnerability URL
CVE-2017-1000408,libc-bin-2.24-11+deb9u3,High,2.24-11+deb9u4,https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2017-1000408
CVE-2017-1000408,libc-dev-bin-2.24-11+deb9u3,High,2.24-11+deb9u4,https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2017-1000408
```

Comment: There are _two_ headers that contain spaces, and you explicitly set the input field separator to a space. Is the input fields separated by multiple spaces (not tabs)?

Comment: Yes, There are two headers. I am not sure it is the output of a program. Is there any way by which I can confirm.

Comment: Note that a single space as input field separator is special. It means "separate fields on any sequences of spaces, tabs and newlines". To avoid splitting your space-containing headers, if your fields are separated by a single `TAB` you may just use `-F "\t"`; for multiple (one or more) tabs, `-F "\t+"`; for a single space, `-F [ ]`; for two or more spaces, `-F [ ]{2,}`. And so on...

Comment: Better use `csvformat`. `awk` would not correctly hands fields that include comma.

Comment: (Of course, in my previous comment I forgot some quotes: `-F '[ ]'`, `-F '[ ]{2,}'`).

Comment: It looks like there is some unavoidable ambiguity in the sample you provided. To get meaningful help, you'll need to help us getting rid of it. I.e. edit your question, clarifying how your columns are separated. (Spaces? Tabs? How many of them?). If you are in doubt, inspect a data sample with something like `<input od -An -tc` (which will show any tab as `\t`).
If columns can be separated in the same way as the words in your headers, e.g. by a single space, then there is likely no standard/safe way to handle it and it is up to you to make assumptions - e.g. handle the header line on its own.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to elaborate the header line differently than the rest of the file. In this particular case:

```
awk 'NR==1 {$0=gensub(/(Vulnerability) (ID|URL)/, "\\1_\\2", "g"); print gensub(/(Vulnerability)_(ID|URL)/, "\\1 \\2", "g", $1","$2","$3","$4","$5)} NR>1 {print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5}' test.txt > file.csv
```

Or:

```
sed -r '1s/(Vulnerability) (ID|URL)/\1_\2/g' test.txt | awk '{print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5}' | sed -r '1s/(Vulnerability)_(ID|URL)/\1 \2/g' > file.csv
```

You've received some very appropriate suggestions in the comments, particularly the one about splitting on multiple space characters and the one suggesting you use other tools to manipulate CSV files. Moreover, if your issue lies solely in the header line, I'd fix it manually if I were you. And...do you really *need* to have spaces in the headers (as opposed to `Vulnerability_URL`)? It all depends on your actual use case.

Splitting on more than one space seems the easiest to me:

```
sed 's/   */,/g' test.txt > file.csv
```